# AngularJS - Save input values in an array for each div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm developing a webapp, where you can add as many formulars as you wish to specify properties. For every formular, an object is pushed into an array with undefined properties. When you press "Accept all", I want to iterate through all the formulars and set the name and the properties, that are typed in. How can I set the attributes of the objects in the array with the content of the input? `$scope.eventName` doesn't work. Maybe there is a misunderstanding regarding the scopes.

I did the same before in `eventCtrl` by adding the properties as a new object to the array when clicking "Accept" for each formular. But I want to automatize it, so that you don't have to click "Accept" on every formular.

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="eventListCtrl">
    <div class="well well-lg" ng-controller="eventCtrl"  ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label><input ng-model="name" ></input><br>
        <label>Properties:</label><input ng-model="propertyName"></input>
        <select ng-model="propertyType">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="addProperty()">Add</button>
    <div>
    <select size="5" id="propertyBox" >
    <option ng-repeat="property in properties"> {{property.name}} : {{property.type}}</option>          
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="deleteEvent()">Delete</button>
   </div>
    <button ng-click="addEvent()">add</button>
    <button ng-click="acceptEvents()"> accept all</button>
</body>
```

And my JS:

```
var events = [];

app.controller('eventListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = events;

    $scope.addEvent = function() {
        events.push({eventName: undefined, eventProperties: undefined});
        console.log(events);
    };

    $scope.acceptEvents = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.events, function(event) {
            name = $scope.eventName ;
        });
        console.log(events);
    };
});

app.controller('eventCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.properties = [];

    $scope.addProperty = function(){
        $scope.properties.push({name: $scope.propertyName, type: $scope.propertyType});
        $scope.propertyName = "";

        console.log(name);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit a work to do but you'll need to generate forms that have unique scope properties for each event in your dataset.

With ng-repeat, you can have it generate a nested object that can store all your data, which you can then use for-loops to iterate through and build out your objects (or whatever you want to do with your data).

This is just an example, but you can do something like this:

```
  $scope.data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

  $scope.property = {};
```

In your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{$index}}
  <input ng-model="property[$index]">
  {{property[$index]}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="p in property">{{p}}</li>
</ul>
```

So the first list, which is generated from your data creates inputs with bindings to the property object that match the index of that object.  The second list is generated from the object populated by the first list.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7whp2QomgfBeVIVOXOq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the intermediate values of event name and properties. So here are the steps.

First, pass the current event to addProperty function like `ng-click="addProperty(event)"`.

Second, set the propertyName and propertyType on the event object
    $scope.event.eventProperties.push({name: $scope.propertyName, type: $scope.propertyType});

Check this working snippet

```js
var events = [];
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('eventListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = events;

    $scope.addEvent = function() {
        events.push({eventName: undefined, eventProperties: []});
        console.log(events);
    };

    $scope.acceptEvents = function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.events, function(event) {
            name = $scope.eventName ;
        });
        console.log(events);
    };
});

app.controller('eventCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.properties = [];

    $scope.addProperty = function(event){
        $scope.event.eventProperties.push({name: $scope.propertyName, type: $scope.propertyType});
        $scope.propertyName = "";

        console.log(name);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" class="container" ng-controller="eventListCtrl">




    <div class="well well-lg" ng-controller="eventCtrl"  ng-repeat="event in events track by $index">
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label><input ng-model="event.eventName" ></input><br>
        <label>Properties:</label><input ng-model="propertyName"></input>
        <select ng-model="propertyType">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="addProperty(event)">Add</button>
    <div>
    <select size="5" id="propertyBox" >
    <option ng-repeat="property in event.eventProperties"> {{property.name}} : {{property.type}}</option>          
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="deleteEvent(event)">Delete</button>
   </div>



    <button ng-click="addEvent()">add</button>
    <button ng-click="acceptEvents()"> accept all</button>


</body>
```